# OOPS: Value doesn't print-(Minor mistake on my part, sorted now)

Tags: php, oop

SOLVED:
I feel naive asking this question but I seem to have gotten stuck in a very simple yet difficult problem. I am not able to understand why I am not able to get the value printed via `show()` while using a simple object oriented concept.

```html
<?php

class Entree
{
     public $name;
     public $ingredients=array();
    
    public function __constructor($name,$ingredients)
    {
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->ingredients=$ingredients;
        
    }
    
    public function show()
    {
        echo $this->name; 
    }
}

$obj=new Entree('soup',['chicken', 'water', 'spice']);
$obj->show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper name of constructor is `__construct()` not `__constructor()` ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)).

Comment: Seriously I am stupid. Wasted like 20 mins going through the code but never imagined I could do such a thing, sorry and thanks.

Comment: No worries, can happen to everyone. Get yourself an IDE or editor with syntax highlighting. It should use different colors for "built-in" functions/methods vs your own, so that helps spotting things like that

Comment: PHPStorm is the best ide for PHP (imo), try it out. You wont regret it, makes your programmer life much easier.

Comment: Have Netbeans but it sucks with intelisense. Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt does that come for free?

Comment: Nope it costs something, but its not much and worth it. If you want a free one, try Netbeans. Or if you are fine with a text editor, i´d go with Sublime3 or VS Code.

Comment: There's 30 days free trial of PHPStorm so you can check if that is something you want to use. But even `vim` highlights that properly, so maybe your Netbeans is just misconfigured?

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt Will check it out

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I guess, I need to check it out. Any resource you could point me towards for configuring my Netbeans properly?

Comment: No, sorry, I am using InteliJ and vim. But I'd guess some googling for "php netbeans highlight" would be a good start.